# Some Unicode Characters are not rendered in Emacs

Tags: unicode, emacs, agda, unicode-string

My emacs has a problem in rendering the Unicode character written by \McU (All \Mc* and \Mi* characters) in Agda input mode. (, , , ... etc)

- I installed Iosevka and JuliaMono Light fonts,
  follwed the instruction in here: https://github.com/rolandwalker/unicode-fonts
- Downloaded font-utils.el / list-utils.el / ucs-utils.el / unicode-fonts.el    in my .emacs.d folder
- Inserted the following in my `.emacs` file:

  ```
  (require 'font-utils)
  (require 'ucs-utils)
  (require 'list-utils)
  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/unicode-fonts/")
  (require 'unicode-fonts)
  (unicode-fonts-setup)
  ```
- And added

  ```
  (set-frame-font "Iosevka SS04" nil t)
  ;; Set a fallback font for mathematical script and fraktur. (It'll mess up monospacing. 
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" '(#x1d49c . #x1d537) "JuliaMono Light")
  ```

  to my `.emacs` file.

None of these works... What can I do?

[image: The unicode character get crashed in emacs]

I expect that Emacs can render unicode characters such as , ...

Actually, I already tried many fonts, modifying my .emacs file. Especially, JuliaMono certainly has this glyph , but still  is not rendered in Emacs.
[JuliaMono font has](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu0St.png)

Comment: Your screen shot and problem description don't seem to indicate a "crash" at all; when Emacs quits unexpectedly or stops responding, that's a crash, but this seems like merely an aesthetic glitch with the font rendering.

Comment: For what it's worth, the only missing glyph in the screen shot appears to be "mathematical bold U" [U+1D414](https://unicodeplus.com/U+1D414)

Comment: The system/font do not have such glyph, so it display with the replacement character `[000 000]` (note: with the Unicode codepoint inside, so it gives you the hint which font you should install)

Comment: Well I already tried a font which has  in its characterset (JuliaMono Light). It's weird...